# Compiling C++ file cannot find mex.h using g++ under mingw

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, mex

I'm currently trying to compile a C++ file that uses a C-style mex API since I'm using MATLAB 2016.

I'm doing this under **mingw** using **g++** on Windows.

However, when I try, it fails to find mex.h. I'm not sure if I need to be editing some environment variable or some kind of PATH. Every example I've found online just simply has the `#include "mex.h"` and that's it.

Is there something I need to do to mingw, or MATLAB, or elsewhere to get this to work?

```
fatal error: mex.h: No such file or directory
#include "mex.h"
          ^~~~~~~
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need somehow to pass flag `-I/your_meh.h_directory` to g++ on compile time.

Comment: `#include "mex.h"` means, that the file `mex.h` is in same folder as the corresponding source file. You can either set the include path or you can move the header file into the directory

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Somehow I thought based on the MATLAB website that mingw automatically handled that by default. I've gone ahead and directed it to where the MATLAB directory is and it works like a charm. Thanks!